# Check the state of checkboxes which were added dynamically

Tags: android, checkbox, onclick

I add my checkboxes dynamically like this:

```
 public void addFiles()
        {

             LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.filesList);

            if(!FileManagerActivity.finalAttachFiles.isEmpty())
            {   

                for (final File file:FileManagerActivity.finalAttachFiles)
                {   

                    Log.i("what I've got", file.toString());
                    View line = new View(this);
                    line.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(1, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    line.setBackgroundColor(0xAA345556);
                    informationView= new CheckBox(this);
                    informationView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    informationView.setTextSize(16);
                    informationView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    informationView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.file_icon, 0, 0, 0);
                    informationView.setText(file.getName().toString());
                    layout.addView(informationView, 0);
                    layout.addView(line, 1);
                    layout.postInvalidate();


                }
            }

        }
```

And I have a button, which onClick event should get the checkable state of those checkboxes and delete which were checked...How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your can add your checkboxes like:

```
for(int i=0;i<totalCB;i++){
    CheckBox chB=new CheckBox(context);
    ...
    chB.setId(i);
    layout.add(...);// add checkbox to view
}
```

now,on click of button,

```
for(int i=0;i<totalCB;i++){
    CheckBox cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(i);
    boolean checked=cd.isChecked();// status of checkbox

    if(checked){
       // perform action 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(int i=0;i<layout.getChildCount;i++){
   if ( ((CheckBox) layout.getChildAt(i)).isChecked() )
                 //remove the Box
}
```

This should do the trick. You may have to alter the code if you have other Views in your layout or create a new layout which only hosts the checkboxes. The Code goes into the OnClick Method of you Buttons onclicklistener of course.

Comment: good idea, I tried to do it like you advice, but I get ClassCastException

Comment: This is the way to go, simply add before the cast: if (child instanceof Checkable) {

Answer (score 0):

You can set id for the checkbox using `informationView.setId(someUniqueInt)`. and then find a text box whereever you want in the activity by

`CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(someUniqueInt)`

And then use

```
if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
     //do whatever you want here
}
```