# How to check RadioButton is checked when added dynamically?

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

In my application I am adding RadioButton dynamically depending on requirement.
Below is the code :

```
RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(StartExamActivity.this);
            View v = new View(StartExamActivity.this);
            v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2));
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3593D4"));
            rg.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            rg.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                rdbtn[i] = new RadioButton(StartExamActivity.this);
                rdbtn[i].setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
                rdbtn[i].setId(i);
                rdbtn[i].setText(list.get(i));
                final String value = rdbtn[i].getText().toString();

                rdbtn[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
                            marks = marks + 2;
                        }
                    }
                });
                rg.addView(rdbtn[i]);
            }
            questionContainer.addView(rg);
```

Now I want to increase the value of **marks** by 2 only ones even when RadioButton is checked multiple times. For that I want to know whether RadioButton is checked or not.
How to do this??

**Please Help!!**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050074/how-to-check-if-radiobutton-is-checked

Comment: Please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855276/cant-get-the-values-from-dynamically-added-check-box) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213545/check-the-state-of-checkboxes-which-were-added-dynamically) hope it will work for u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple thing,  
Why don't you use `OnClickListener` instead of `onCheckedChanged`>

```
rdbtn[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                        if(isChecked) {
                           // Write your logic here...
                        }
                    });
```